# Inconsistent assigning of values to Variables using tf.assign()

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning Tensor flow and trying to capture each iteration duration into a summary variable. I've identified it to a peculiar issue which I summarise in following code

1) define a tensor (to capture start / end time)

```
t = tf.Variable(0.0, tf.float64)
```

2) run iterations and output time at each iteration

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables()))
    for i in range(20):
        _ = time.time()
        sess.run(tf.assign(t,_)) #update 't' tensor value to start time
        print("time_1: {}, time_2_tensor: {} ".format(_,sess.run(t)))
```

when I run the code, I wonder why large discrepancy (4-5 sec) between *time_1* & *time_2_tensor* value. Here's Output (time_1 seems more correct, and wonder why time_2_tensor seems future time and all the same value!

> time_1: 1510622147.797711, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.823721, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.846073, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.872359, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.893345, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.913889, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.94033, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.960254, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622147.98226, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.007267, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.045414, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.072437, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.104469, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.124364, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.143735, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.161832, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.179756, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.216838, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.235228, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0
>
> time_1: 1510622148.254686, time_2_tensor: 1510622208.0

Thanks a lot for any insight into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data type is not being considered when declaring the variable (it's taking the place of argument `trainable`, at least in [v1.4](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable)) and becomes then a `float32`, which leads to precision issues.

It works if you add the keyword `dtype`.

```
t = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=tf.float64)
```

The 'experiment':

```
t_bad = tf.Variable(0.0, tf.float64)
t = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=tf.float64)

print(t_bad.dtype)  # <dtype: 'float32_ref'>
print(t.dtype)  # <dtype: 'float64_ref'>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was driving me nut full half-day. I had a hunch it was to do with float overflow, but dint know we had to explicitly mention `dtype` argument!